# SWI setting R0 to 0

Tags: assembly, arm

Why does the following ARM code set `R0` to `0` after the `SWI`?

```
    .equ    SWI_CheckButton, 0x203

    .global _start
    .text   
_start:

mov R0, #1
swi SWI_CheckButton
```

I'm trying to right a program that takes the form

```
FunctionA:
    swi SWI_CheckButton
    cmp R0, #1
    beq label1
    cmp R0, #2
    beq lablel2
    ...
    cmp R0, #9
    beq label9
    label1:
    ...
    label9:
        @do work
        bal FunctionA
```

This gets messed up in `label9` because I want it to remember the last key that was pressed but `swi SWI_CheckButton` resets `R0` to `0` (I guess if nothing is pressed).

The problem is `swi 0x203` resets `R0` to `0` so where would I find a `swi` that does the same thing but doesn't reset `R0`?

Comment: Can you show us your SWI handler code?

Comment: I don't think my program has one. I'm writing for the Embest board.

Comment: Generally, SWI handlers save and restore registers so that register values are restored across SWIs. I am not sure what your SWI handler is doing. Search for `SWI_Handler` in your entire source and see if one exists

Comment: Sorry there isn't. It only does this with this particular swi, for example the swi to flash a light doesn't change the value of r0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually [found an example](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:9y7UNjYpONwJ%3ahttps://connex.csc.uvic.ca/access/content/group/ARMSim/SIMWeb/AttachedFiles/ARMSim_UserGuide4Plus.pdf%20Embest%20board%20swi%200x203&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShDe7EPz-iaKGhQaYToJePoIfm0tntHXVhhwCeIGRUCCYdSMhfohapnbB3hBxPZamLCC95z4sGhdH-QYk9pRghll7kCAlak-5x2Q48PlHLtiqv8HzDQB4elPU0TKjk3ESCc0DWf&sig=AHIEtbR8a2sTUgonTd6ncrnwJ0Bnq-JzEw&pli=1) for that SWI.  Do a search for `SWI_CheckBlue`.  What happens is the code of the key being pressed is returned by the SWI routine in R0.  If R0 is zero on return, it means no key was being pressed at the time the SWI was called.

You probably need to loop round until it comes out non zero.

Comment: @user1279820: I think it was eventually a Google search on SWI and 203.

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that that SWI has a return value (maybe zero indicates *false*?)

You need to store the value you want in another register, and restore it after the call. If you don't have a spare register, you'll have to save it to the stack.

Comment: Unless `cheks for a button` is another way of saying `just waits for a button`, it should indeed somehow return the code of the pressed key (if any) or the appropriate "none" code (if none).